# Entity Framework works locally but not on iis

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, iis

In my MVC project, I'm trying to get data using  "$.ajax" and entity framework, and everything is OK on the local machine, but when I publish my website on the same machine but to IIS I get Server Error (500).
I tried many solution but all are not work?
Should I modify anything in the web.config?

```
    <connectionStrings>
        <add name="TrachingDBEntities2" connectionString="metadata=res://*/Model1.csdl|res://*/Model1.ssdl|res://*/Model1.msl;provider=System.Data.SqlClient;provider connection string=&quot;
data source=localhost;initial catalog=TrachingDB;integrated 
security=True;multipleactiveresultsets=True;application name=EntityFramework&quot;" providerName="System.Data.EntityClient" />
      </connectionStrings>
```

Comment: What makes you think it's entity framework not working?

Comment: entity framework working locally, but not on the IIS?

Comment: How do you know it is entity framework that is the problem?

Comment: Because it's working when I tried to get the same data without using entity framework!